Why the background image in my code is getting disappeared as soon as I apply absolute position to it?
I am trying to clone netflix UI but getting error while applying the background image with its position as absolute with top:0. I have attached both html and css codes. Please help me out in identifying the issue.
I have already given relative position to parent-container.


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.parent-container{
    position: relative;
    height: 120vh;
    width: auto;
}

/* header nav .logo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
} */

.frontPage{
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: max(1500px,100%);
    filter: brightness(0.5);
    width: auto;
    height: 110vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Clone - Netflix</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent-container">

        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/30/30" alt="Netflix icon"> 
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="frontPage">

        </div>


    </div>
    
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>




The problem is that you are setting width: auto. When the div element has no position attribute defined, it will take up 100% of its container due to its default of block display styling. However, when you add position: absolute, it no longer has a basis for its width and the width will shrink to 0.
You can see in this snippet that the red rectangle shows, while the blue cannot be seen.


<div style="width: 400px; height: 100vh;">
  <div style="height: 100px; background: red;"></div>
  <div style="height: 50px; background: blue; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></div>
</div>




Yes, I got it. Thanks but with position: relative, the same is working fine even with width: auto. Can you please help me understand the logic behind it.

Sure, so this is all about the concept of "document flow", this article explains exactly what's going on: https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning When setting position: relative, the div maintains its position in the document flow and therefore keeps its basis for width. Using absolute or fixed however pulls the div out of the document flow and it no longer knows how wide to be without specific instructions

You need to give .frontPage a width other than auto. Either set width: 100% or set right: 0

You need to add a width (ex 100vw) to your .frontPage class and also set z-index to -1 to show your logo above


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.parent-container{
    position: relative;
    height: 120vh;
    width: auto;
}

/* header nav .logo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
} */

.frontPage{
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: max(1500px,100%);
    filter: brightness(0.5);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 110vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:-1;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Clone - Netflix</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent-container">

        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/30/30" alt="Netflix icon"> 
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="frontPage">

        </div>


    </div>
    
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>



